# Soap Authentication implementation thru WSDL and Schema

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, xsd, ws-security

I need some clue or direction on how to implement authentication into soap message.

Is it possible to implement authentication by using plain WSDL and Xml Schema ?

When I said plain, I referring to only using WSDL / XML schema, no php, no java annotation, no ruby, no .net, etc.

I know there are standards on WSS, which is SAML / OASIS, but from their documentation (only OASIS, I haven't access SAML documentation yet) they are focus on their specification on soap message, which isn't what i want.

On top of that, I want soap authentication, not http basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

A WSDL is simply the description of the service. It doesn't implement *anything*, and certainly doesn't implement authentication.

Also, FYI, there's no such thing as SOAP Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach would be to use the WS-Security standard. The easiest way to achieve a solution would be to use WS-Security Username token policy described here:

https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm

The benefit of using this approach is that your WSDL will include a  section that will describe the authentication requirements of the web service. Any clients that generate stubs using the WSDL will then be able to automatically generate code for including username token with the request message.

You can find an example implementation here:

[WS Security - Username token Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281495/ws-security-username-token-profile)

Comment: the example you given have to implement from java. i don want involve any programming language if possible, just plain schema and wsdl. thanks.

Comment: yup, i read this too, but what describes here oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/… <br> are those specification in soap envelope itself. <br> what i want is as what you said, "the wsdl will include a section that will describe the authentication requirement of web service.", but i cant find what should i include in my wsdl or how to implement my schema, from that documentation.