# SOAP WS authentication in Websphere

Tags: web-services, soap, ws-security, websphere-8

I'm new to both SOAP WS and Websphere Application Server(8.5).

I have a web service which is currently accessed over http and my objectives are :

1. Changing the access protocol from http to https
2. Implementing the authentication for the users which are located in an Active Directory group

I went through several stackoverflow threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281495/ws-security-username-token-profile) and I also tried attaching 'policy set' to the web service and somehow now its accessible only over https despite of detaching policy sets. Then, I also created custom policy sets and bindings as per [IBM developer blog](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1103_balakrishnan/1103_balakrishnan.html#_Step_1:_Deploy) but every time I invoke the WS (using SOAP UI) as follows :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.scania.com/logistics/schema/transport/v1">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7AEC79B67DC85BBB5A14210677185104">
            <wsse:Username>12345</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">12345</wsse:Password>

         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:TransportInformationRequest>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <v1:ChassisNumber>2105909</v1:ChassisNumber>
      </v1:TransportInformationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get an error on the server side :

```
Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options ,Oracle JDBC driver 11.2.0.2.0).
[2015-01-12 14:17:09:525 CET] 000000b1 AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive Must Understand check failed for headers: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for headers: {http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.handler.HandlerUtils.checkMustUnderstand(HandlerUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.inboundHeaderAndHandlerProcessing(EndpointController.java:338)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.handleRequest(EndpointController.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:103)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:909)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1066)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

When I remove the header and simply pass the body, the response is correct.

I understand that the web service isn't configured properly to handle the header but I'm really not able establish the way I should proceed.

Any relevant inputs are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is JAX-WS and your active directory is your websphere registry, you can follow this article to add WS-Security constraints for a UsernameToken:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_stand_alone_security_token.html

If active directory is not your WebSphere registry, then you must also do this and write code to do the authentication to AD in custom code:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_replace_authmethod_usernametoken.html

If you had to do that 2nd step there and you also want WebSphere credentials for the user, you must do this:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_config_wssec_caller_no_reg.html

In order to get HTTPS, at the point in the 1st article when you were adding the WS-Security policy type to the policy set, you would also add the SSLTransport policy type.

Comment: For anyone who thinks that this post should be deleted because it has links, I can't create a post out of the content in the links. The engine insists that the code is not formatted correctly so I can't post it (the code compiles and I've marked it and did ctrl-k at least 10x on it with no results). If someone thinks that they can make a super-long post out of these links, please do.